# show that if a family of sets is closed under union, then the complements of those sets form a family that is closed under intersection

Tags: combinatorics

I am reading a survey on Frankl's Conjecture.  It is stated without commentary that the set of complements of a union-closed family is intersection-closed. I need some clearer indication of why this is true,  though I guess it is supposed to be obvious.

Comment: Are you familiar with [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)?

Answer (score 1):

This is because we can rewrite $(A \cup B)^C = A^C \cap B^C$ using [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Now, if $\mathbb{S}$ is the family of sets closed under union and $A, B \in \mathbb{S}$, then $A \cup B \in \mathbb{S}$ (since it's closed under union). Therefore, $(A\cup B)^C \in \mathbb{S}^C$ (by the definition of the complement family). Hence, $A^C \cap B^C = (A \cup B) ^C \in \mathbb{S}^C$

Comment: thanks. I know how I went wrong now.  I was trying to do a proof by contradiction and it's more straightforward than that!

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if you are talking about union of two sets or arbitrary unions. In either case the result is true and it is an easy consequence of DeMorgan's Law: $(\cup_i A_i)^{c}=\cap_i A_I^{c}$.